# How could I make similarly evolved "aliens" living in volcanoes more plausible?

Tags: planets, creature-design, science-fiction, space

I am writing a story, and it takes place in a solar system way far off from our own. One of the planets, Veynerth, is a dry, deserty planet, but in certain areas there is high volcanic activity. However, the species that live on this planet and have mostly civilized it actually live inside of dormant volcanoes and the areas around it. I don't know if that would really be possible, and I have been trying to make it seem more plausible. The one thing that helps is that it's sci-fi, and we don't even know what type of worlds are out there, so there's some room for unexplained things.

The "aliens" are much like humans. They have thicker eyelashes to protect their eyes from falling ash, etc. but their hair is also thicker. Their skin is dry and some areas are almost scaley. Their eyes are adapted to see in dark conditions. Some help with the features and how the species SHOULD be would also be helpful.

Comment: The main question is why. What is the reason for them to be inside the volcanoes?

Comment: An *entire* civilization or species that *only* lives in/on dormant volcanoes seems unlikely. Is that what you're looking for? Without something actively keeping them away from other types of terrain they would spread out, just as we did.

Comment: @rek see my below comment

Comment: @Tim B I hadn't really thought about that, but that is a great point. I feel like they'd need to live inside of the volcanoes because there wouldn't be much resources in the outside world to build their own structures. Not to mention with the constant fall of ash, the unstable and cracked and dry ground.. that's not saying no one can live out there, though. It just wouldn't be enough to sustain a whole "city".

Comment: A desert planet with lots of volcanic activity would be very problematic for life developing and for e.g. ongoing agriculture.  I think it's also quite difficult to identify a dormant volcano and I wonder if any volcanoes that were thought to be dormant have ever erupted without warning ?

Comment: Welcome to WorldBuilding *Alyssa*! Interesting question. You might be interested in the tag [tag:creature-design] (and this might be a good addition to your tags). Clarifications should also go into the question body in addition to the comments, as comments can be purged theoretically at any point and for any reason while answers and questions have a revision history and are what posts are judged by - not the comments. If you have a moment please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about the site. Have fun!

Comment: The aliens would only live within a volcano's caldera if they couldn't live outside. Two reason's off the top of my head: its freezing outside and the only habitable temperature is inside the caldera; alternatively, the aliens have evolved to breathe $SO_2$, and will suffocate if they leave. The problem with both these theories and the OP's scenario is that this explains _one_ volcano. Either parallel evolution took place across dozens of volcanoes, or the aliens were able to migrate to other volcanoes without benefit of maps, over deadly terrain. Neither option is particularly believable.

Comment: The biggest problem for me is that they're humanoid. Nothing about their environment should make them human like. If they lived along a large mountain range of dormant and active volcanoes, which utilized the caves for different  reasons while still being active outside, it could work. But as is, you're having to handwave too much.

Comment: @nzaman Perhaps they have a stage of their life cycle where they can survive outside and use that to migrate but they need the volcanoes to breed.

Comment: @TimB: Consider the probabilities of finding a volcano within a limited time frame without map or a GPS. Consider also that in order to evolve such a stage of survival, they need to have evolved this habit before their brains evolved to human levels of intelligence and factor that in. One in a million survival rate before breeding is all right for fish but really not conducive to breeding for intelligence

Comment: @nzaman I was thinking that they could survive weeks or months outside during the migratory stage of their life cycle, and they would use that to "island hop" from volcano to volcano. Originally this evolved in a group of close together volcanoes, then range would gradually extend.

Comment: @TimB: That is the part I have a problem with. Volcanoes can't be too close together, or one will set off the other, then they'll merge. At least hundreds of kilometres apart is what I'd expect. Now, if two volcanoes are 100 km apart, the search area is 30,000 sq. km., 200 km becomes 120,000 sq.km. to search. Granted, you can't really miss a volcano, if you're heading in roughly the right direction, but a) nobody has come back to say they found one thataway and b) this is presumably before they had a language to communicate in.

Comment: @nzaman I'm sorry, you are just flat wrong. Here's just one example https://news.nationalgeographic.com/news/2010/02/100219-volcanoes-erupt-simultaneously-kamchatka-picture/ of volcanoes right next to each other. You'll note they don't even share a magma chamber so it's not like they are different vents to one volcano.

Comment: @TimB: Not really disproving my point. I quote `volcanoes' close proximity makes it more, not less, likely that they'd explode in unison`. Given a few thousand years, they will merge as the flowing magma wears out the rock. I'll grant you that I'm assuming continuous flow, and that might not really happen, but on average how many volcanoes are less than 100 km of each other?

Comment: @nzaman Flowing magma creates more rock not less. That's why the conical mountains form. Do you have any source for your theory that they will merge?

Comment: @TimB: Strangely, there don't seem to be any articles that explicitly state volcanoes merge, though they seem to imply it. The closest I got was [this page](https://sites.google.com/site/kbisathimb/physical-environment/geology), apparently from the Hawaii Institute of Marine Biology, which mentions volcanoes merging as part of a timeline. Also similar: https://books.google.com.bd/books?id=J4PlBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA145&lpg=PA145&dq=volcanoes+merge&source=bl&ots=VwwmsRcZo5&sig=eDT2_VV4CgqY4KwFeecfylJmQZI&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjq6rDlrfHZAhUB3Y8KHf5WDIEQ6AEIkAEwDA , but I don't have context

Comment: @nzaman Volcanoes can merge, no-one disputes that. There is a big leap to go from "can" to "must" though.

Answer (score 1):

Your scenario is very similar to the communities of organisms that live around deep sea vents.

[image: deep sea tube worms]
[image: deep sea vent barnacles]

As @nzaman alludes to in the comments, the vent offers resources not available otherwise on the ocean floor - chemical energy for the taking and heat.  Your volcanoes can be exactly the same - they provide chemistry and heat that the aliens cannot get elsewhere on their world.

@nzaman comment about dispersal is also exactly relevant to deep sea vents.  How do vent creatures traverse the dark freezing wastes of the ocean bottom to colonize other vents?

https://www.whoi.edu/oceanus/feature/the-mysterious-movements-of-deep-sea-larvae

> Here’s the catch: The vents are distributed intermittently along
>   mid-ocean ridges—the long volcanic mountain chains that bisect the
>   seafloor throughout the globe. These vents “turn on” and “turn off,”
>   fueled by the ebbs and flows of hot magma beneath the seafloor.
>
> So how do the larvae, tinier than specks of dust, maintain their
>   populations in such a patchy, transient environment? How do they get
>   transported from one active vent site to another that might be tens of
>   miles or more away?

The answer: larval forms with onboard resources to weather the trip that make use of ocean currents between vents.

So too your aliens.  They need to have a dispersal phase that can traverse the waste in search of new volcanoes.  Maybe larval forms?  Or maybe they are like ants or termites - a winged generation is born which leaves their ancestral volcano and sets off in search of new lands.

Comment: The aliens are described as being "much like humans" which would, in my mind, rule out a winged larval stage.

Comment: @rek - but humans can gear up and trek across the unknown.  Maybe every 30 years certain children were chosen at birth to be the travelers and this group set out when they came of age.  This would all be history, of course - to explain how the intelligent humanoid aliens colonized the entirety of the planet volcano by volcano.

Comment: @WillK that's an amazing idea, and in the world I set this in, it makes perfect sense! I have been struggling with the history of the planet and that gives me a really good starting point- their ancestors travelling far across the dangerous planet, colonizing it to what it currently is, and it still leaves space for important discoveries, big events, etc. Thank you so much for your contribution